# How to keep focus in input element where Enter was pressed to submit form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, user-interface

Form contains input elements and submit button. Pressing Submit button shows pdf file in new tab in browser.
If enter is pressed to show report, focus moves to submit button. After selection report parameters tag again additional click in input element is required to enter new value to same element.

How to keep focus input element where enter was pressed ?

```
<form id="Form" class='form-fields' method='post' target='_blank'
action='Render'>

<input id='test' name='test' value='test' /> 
...
  <input id='_submit' type='submit' value='Show report' /> 
</form>
```

jquery, jqueryui, asp.net mvc2 are used.

**update**

I have 2 elements with same name in form to allow unchecked checkbox submission:

```
<input type='hidden' value='false' name='Summary' />
<input type='checkbox' id='Summary' name='Summary' checked />
<select class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="_Report" name="_Report" size="10">
<option value="LV001">Report1</option>
<option value="LV003">Report2</option>
<option selected="selected" value="LV009">Report3</option>
</select>
```

I tried code below as suggested in comment. If focus is in checkbox, it focus is not restored. Instead select element is focused. How to fix ?

```
        $("#Form input:not([type=submit]), textarea, select").focus(function () {
            $('input').removeClass('hasFocus');
            $(this).addClass('hasFocus');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get back to the last focused item, I think you will need to keep track on the last focused item.

Something like this will probably achieve what you are looking for:

```
$(function() {
    var lastFocus = [];

    $('#Form').find(':text,:radio,:checkbox,select,textarea').focus(function() {
        lastFocus = $(this);
    });

    $('#Form').submit(function(){    
        if (lastFocus.length == 1)
            lastFocus.focus();

        // just to prevent the actual submit - remove this to enable submit
        return false;
    });
});
```

I also made a jsfiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/Jht6C/

Comment: @Christoffer- when focus is on button and i push Esc key, control should remain in same button. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Or since you are already using jQuery, you could probably also use this simple function to set focus on submit:

```
$(function() {

    $('#Form').submit(function(){    

        $('#test').focus();

    });

});
```

This way focus will be set to "#test" as soon as the form is submitted.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vZSZT/

Edit:

To get focus back to where it was when form was submitted, I would probably do it this way:

```
$(function() {

    //Lets make sure we dont target the submit-input
    $("input:not([type=submit])").focus(function () {

        //Remove previous focused inputs
        $('input').removeClass('hasFocus');    

        //Add focus class to this input
        $(this).addClass('hasFocus');

    });


    $('#Form').submit(function(){    

        $('.hasFocus').focus();


    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vZSZT/4/

However, Christoffer´s way seems to be good too (and probably even better? I cant tell), but both will work :)

Comment: Form contains lot of input elements. In your example element id #test is hard coded. How to determine in submit the element where cursor was if enter was pressed and set focus to this element, not to #test element always ?

Comment: @Andrej both Will work indeed. Just a note about your code which could be worth thinking about, is that it only works with input elements (not selects and textareas). Also it affects inputs over the entire page, not just the mentioned form.

Comment: @Christoffer: Thats true, but it can be easily modified by changing the selector. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @op: if you need the script to work with select and textareas too, you can do so by adding them in the selector like this $('input:not([type=submit]), textarea, select') and if you want to target the mentioned form only add: $('#Form input:not([type=submit]), textarea, select'). Thanks again to Christoffer for mentioning it!

Comment: @Andrej: I tried Andrej last suggestoin but if focus in in checkbox it is not restored. I updated question

Comment: @Christoffer Christoffer  solution works in this case also, so I marked it as answer

Comment: To me it seems working with checkboxes too since they are covered by the selector "input:not([type=submit])". Also I can see in Firebug that the class "hasFocus" gets applied to the checkbox correctly, but probably I missed something. Go with Christoffers way if there are no problems there :)

Comment: @Andrej: Steps to reproduce: if select element has focus, click in submit using mouse. after that put focus to input type=text element and click again in submit button. In this case focus is put to select element, not to input element. Maybe both elemens have hasFocus class in this case. Issue is not related to checkbox, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Andrus: You are right. We forgot the following: You see in the code the line where we remove the current focus, right? ($('input').removeClass('hasFocus');). As you can probably see now, we are only removing the focus class from input elements. If you change this line to: $('input, textarea, select').removeClass('hasFocus'); it will work. Additionally you can add the "#Form", so we make sure we are only removing the focus class from elements inside the mentioned form. Check this demo for the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/vZSZT/5/ (i hope i did not forget anything again :S )

Comment: @Andrus: But keep using Christoffer´s way - It seems that its cleaner and a bit smaller. I just wanted to show you where the error was - so you can fix it yourself the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a simple solution for focusing after form submit. Add the keyword `autofocus` as an attribute to the input-element.

```
<input id='test' name='test' value='test' autofocus>
```